# Let g in G be an element of finite order. Find the order of $g^m$ where $m \ge 0$.

Tags: group-theory

[image: 1] 
[image: 2]

I understand how it goes from saying that md is a multiple of |g|. But am unable to understand why the statement right after is true.

Answer (score 1):

$m|g^m|$ is $md$, where $d$ is least positive integer $d$ for which $md$ is a multiple of $|g|$. Therefore, it's the least positive integer divisible by both $m$ and $|g|$.

For example, think about finding $lcm(4,6)$.  We start listing multiples of $4$ and stop at $12$ since that's also a multiple of $6$.  So $lcm(4,6)=12$.